# How to store checked list state in listview android?

Tags: android, checkbox, simplecursoradapter, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am using listview to display three textviews(values for these text views where come from database) and one checkbox. I would like to store the checkbox state when ever the user clicks the checkbox and display it when they came back. But, i am new to android development and i haven't got any idea how to do it. I have tried adding checkbox to the list view, but the onitemclick is disabled.Below are the code,

This is the cursor to retrieve values from database and list in listview,

```
Cursor yearcursor = db.paymentall(this); 
 String[] yearfrom = new String[]  
{ PaymentAppDataBase.REQUESTEDDATE,PaymentAppDataBase.PAYMENTNAME,PaymentAppDataBase.AMOUNT };
 int[] yearto = new int[] { R.id.Date,R.id.Name,R.id.Amount };

            SimpleCursorAdapter yearadapter =

 new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, yearcursor, yearfrom, yearto);

setListAdapter(yearadapter);

 amount.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,

 long id) {


 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


 String toaddressreview = cursor.getString(4);

 String subjectreview = cursor.getString(5);

 String emailbodyreview = cursor.getString(6);

 Intent todayreview = new Intent(ReviewPayment.this,ReviewandResend.class);

todayreview.putExtra("toadd", toaddressreview);

 todayreview.putExtra("subjectreveiew", subjectreview);

 todayreview.putExtra("emailbody", emailbodyreview);

 startActivity(todayreview);

 }

});
```

**Mt xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:paddingTop="4dip"

android:paddingBottom="6dip"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="horizontal">


 <TextView android:id="@+id/Date"

 android:layout_width="100dip"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:textSize="14sp"/>


<TextView android:id="@+id/Name"

 android:layout_width="120dip"

android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

android:layout_weight="2" 

 android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"

 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Date"/>


<TextView android:id="@+id/Amount"

 android:layout_width="50dip"

android:layout_height="20dip"  

 android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" 

 android:layout_weight="2"

 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Name"/>


<CheckBox

 android:id="@+id/checkBox1"

 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

 android:layout_height="50dip"

 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Amount"

 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Amount" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great if i get the answer for two questions,

**1.** How to save the state of the checkbox?

**2.** How to enable onitemclicklistener while using checkbox?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no easy way but to keep an array of boolean equal to the number of your list items and store the state. You need to make this a member variable of the custom adapter that you derive from your SimpleCursorAdapter.
2. Again, it needs to be part of your custom adapter. In your getView() function of the adapter, you need to implement the onCheckedChangeListener() [don't recall the exact name right now] for the checkbox and in your main Activity where you have the listview, set the onItemClickListener() to the listview.

If this doesn't make sense, just go through a bit in stackoverflow. This question has been dealt with numerous times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My list view is not constant it will change dynamically.. In that case what will be the answer.. thanks

Comment: How do you plan to update the listview? Are u going to make a new cursor and assign it to your listview everytime the cursor changes or are you going to do a notifydatasetchanged() ? If its the first case, then your adapter's constructor needs to handle the recreation of the boolean array. If its the second case, then you will have to override the notifydatasetchanged() method and implement the change in number of items in the list and its effect in it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I am using first approach. I am updating the listview using SimpleCursorAdapter.. I will try your answer..